# Animating a shape in GUI with threads

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swing, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Exercise2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable{
public int x = 20;

public Exercise2(){
     setSize(400, 200);
     setTitle("Moving Car");
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     JButton move = new JButton("Move the car");
     move.addActionListener(this);
     add(move , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawRect(x, 80, 80, 50);
    g.drawOval(x, 130, 30, 30);
    g.drawOval(x+50, 130, 30, 30);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  Thread t = new Thread(this);
  t.run();
}
public void run(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 400; i += 10){
      x += 10;
      repaint();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
public static void main(String []args){
 new Exercise2();
}}
```

this is my first time asking a question on this site, so i apologize in advance for my mistakes.

im currently studying threads and im supposed to make the car move with the press of a button, but when i press the button instead of moving it just skips and appears on the other side after my selected time. 
how can i fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t.run();
```

The above is incorrect. When using a Thread you need to use:

```
t.start();
```

When you invoke the run() method directly, the method executes on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is the Thread that repaints the GUI. When you tell the thread to sleep, it can't repaint the GUI until the loop finishes executing. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Also, this in not the way to do custom painting. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame. Again read the tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).